# Which technology to use for playing audio on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio

I need something that is capable of:

- playing audio files (whatever preferred format, I'm flexible)
- play more than one at once (=mixing it automatically to the headphones/speaker)

and if possible:
- play from a particular position of an audio file, i.e. starting at 2 seconds rather than from the beginning

where should I have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [AudioQueue](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AboutAudioQueues/AboutAudioQueues.html)

It is very easy to implement (just search for AudioQueue on Stack Overflow) and very powerful if needed.